# Getting U_STRINGPREP_PROHIBITED_ERROR when trying to deploy MongoDB on Kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

Trying to set up MongoDB in a Kubernetes cluster on my local machine using Minikube but getting the following error. (I tried multiple MongoDB images; latest, 5.0.0, 4.0, etc. The problem continued.)

My `mongodb-secret.yaml` is as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mongodb-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  mongo-root-username: dXNlcm5hbWUNCg==
  mongo-root-password: cGFzc3dvcmQNCg==
```

My `mongodb-deployment.yaml` file is as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb-deployment
  labels:
    apps: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        env:
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-username 
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-password
```

The output when I run `kubectl get all`:

```
NAME                                      READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/mongodb-deployment-6c587ddcbb-lnk2q   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6          7m56s

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   6d

NAME                                 READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/mongodb-deployment   0/1     1            0           14m

NAME                                            DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/mongodb-deployment-59ff8f9fd7   0         0         0       9m1s
replicaset.apps/mongodb-deployment-6c587ddcbb   1         1         0       7m56s
replicaset.apps/mongodb-deployment-7fc5cbcf9c   0         0         0       10m
replicaset.apps/mongodb-deployment-8f6675bc5    0         0         0       14m
```

The output when I run `kubectl logs mongodb-deployment-6c587ddcbb-lnk2q`:

```
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 28

{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.738+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"main","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.740+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.741+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.741+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.741+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":28,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"mongodb-deployment-6c587ddcbb-lnk2q"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.741+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.6","gitVersion":"72e66213c2c3eab37d9358d5e78ad7f5c1d0d0d7","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu1804","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.741+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"18.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.741+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1","port":27017,"tls":{"mode":"disabled"}},"processManagement":{"fork":true,"pidFilePath":"/tmp/docker-entrypoint-temp-mongod.pid"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/proc/1/fd/1"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.741+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22297,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.742+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=12285M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.855+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1623831333:855500][28:0x7f583f1b6ac0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.855+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1623831333:855566][28:0x7f583f1b6ac0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global oldest timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.865+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":123}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.865+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.886+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4366408, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"No table logging settings modifications are required for existing WiredTiger tables","attr":{"loggingEnabled":true}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.887+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.894+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.894+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22178,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'. We suggest setting it to 'never'","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.894+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20320,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"createCollection","attr":{"namespace":"admin.system.version","uuidDisposition":"provided","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"5118c0eb-1d88-4b4a-837c-ec78ce97b710"}},"options":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"5118c0eb-1d88-4b4a-837c-ec78ce97b710"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.908+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"namespace":"admin.system.version","index":"_id_","commitTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.908+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":20459,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Setting featureCompatibilityVersion","attr":{"newVersion":"4.4"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.908+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.909+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20320,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"createCollection","attr":{"namespace":"local.startup_log","uuidDisposition":"generated","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"5e09a18c-0532-4fad-8981-283eb3f2f429"}},"options":{"capped":true,"size":10485760}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.924+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"namespace":"local.startup_log","index":"_id_","commitTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.924+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.925+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20712,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap","msg":"Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions reap interval","attr":{"error":"NamespaceNotFound: config.system.sessions does not exist"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.925+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20320,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"createCollection","attr":{"namespace":"config.system.sessions","uuidDisposition":"generated","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"8149a51f-47fd-4180-a6a4-310574dfae9b"}},"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.925+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.926+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"127.0.0.1"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.926+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
child process started successfully, parent exiting
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.948+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"namespace":"config.system.sessions","index":"_id_","commitTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.948+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"namespace":"config.system.sessions","index":"lsidTTLIndex","commitTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.961+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:55144","connectionId":1,"connectionCount":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.961+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:55144","client":"conn1","doc":{"application":{"name":"MongoDB Shell"},"driver":{"name":"MongoDB Internal Client","version":"4.4.6"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"Ubuntu","architecture":"x86_64","version":"18.04"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:33.964+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:55144","connectionId":1,"connectionCount":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:34.003+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:55146","connectionId":2,"connectionCount":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:34.004+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:55146","client":"conn2","doc":{"application":{"name":"MongoDB Shell"},"driver":{"name":"MongoDB Internal Client","version":"4.4.6"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"Ubuntu","architecture":"x86_64","version":"18.04"}}}}
uncaught exception: Error: couldn't add user: Error preflighting normalization: U_STRINGPREP_PROHIBITED_ERROR :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1386:11
@(shell):1:1
Error saving history file: FileOpenFailed Unable to open() file /home/mongodb/.dbshell: No such file or directory
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T08:15:34.016+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:55146","connectionId":2,"connectionCount":0}}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Checking your secret values, something's wrong:

```
$ echo  dXNlcm5hbWUNCg==| base64 --decode | cat -e
username^M$
$ echo  cGFzc3dvcmQNCg== | base64 --decode | cat -e
password^M$
```

Try re-creating your secret without those un-printable characters (`\r` as well as `\n`).

Maybe, instead of pre-encoding your secret, you could try:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mongodb-secret
type: Opaque
stringData:
  mongo-root-username: username
  mongo-root-password: password
```

Comment: Thank you for your remark on the secret values. Something was indeed wrong with them. I think it might be due to Windows' different line ending style. I am not sure though.

Anyways, used an online base64 encoder-decoder and removed the unwanted line ending characters from my secret username and password and everything worked. 

Comment: confirmed, you can use `echo -n 'username'|base64` for encoding

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. So I converted the username and password using the below commands and it worked.
can you use the exact code as shown below while converting into base64:

```
echo -n 'username' | base64  
 
echo -n 'password' | base64
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't execute the `echo username | base64` in Windows.
Do it in WSL or some other Linux flavor.
Then the results will be correct and pod/mongo-deployment will work without errors.

Answer (score -1):

I faced some issues with Secrets configurations. Solution provided above did not help in my case.
Below quick fix worked for me.

1. I removed the configuration for env attribute.

   Then ran the `kubectl apply -f configuration_filename.yaml` command
   to apply changes.
2. Add the env & again run `kubectl apply -f configuration_filename.yaml` command.

Hope it works.